# Convert a feed into XML from PHP/SQL

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to convert a feed from my database to XML this code is clear but its not working nothing. no errors, Nothing. Even a single echo is not showing up. My datas are imported correctly in an other file.

```
<?php 
include_once 'connect.php';
?>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$xml_document = new DOMDocument( '1.0','utf-8' );
$xml_document->formatOutput = true;
/**
 * Create Root Element
*/
$root = $xml_document->createElement( "source" );
$xml_document->appendChild( $root ); //append root element to document

$publisher = $xml_document->createElement( "publisher" );
$publisher->appendChild( $xml_document->createTextNode( "Latifa" ) ) );
$root->appendChild( $publisher );

/**
 * Define Site URL
*/
$publisherurl = $xml_document->createElement( "publisherUrl" );
$publisherurl->appendChild( $xml_document->createTextNode("https://www.latifa.com") );
$root->appendChild( $publisherurl );


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='job_listing' AND post_status='publish'";
        $result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        foreach($result as $result){

    // Start Job Element
    $job_element = $xml_document->createElement( "job" );

    // Job title
    $title = $xml_document->createElement("title");
    $title->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( $result['post_title'] ) );
    $job_element->appendChild( $title );

    // Apply Url

    $applyUrl= $xml_document->createElement("applyUrl");
    $applyUrl->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( $result['guid']));
    $job_element->appendChild($applyUrl);

    // Desc
    $description = $xml_document->createElement("description");
    $description->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( $result['post_content']));
    $job_element->appendChild($description);

    $idone=$result['ID'];
        $meta="SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id=$idone AND meta_key IN ('geolocation_city','geolocation_country_short','_company_name')";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,$meta);
                foreach($query as $query){

                    if($query['meta_key'] == "geolocation_city"){
                            $city = $xml_document->createElement("city");
                            $city->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( $query['meta_value']));
                            $job_element->appendChild($city);

                }
                     if($query['meta_key'] == "geolocation_country_short"){
                      $country = $xml_document->createElement("country");
                        $country->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( $query['meta_value']));
                        $job_element->appendChild($country);
                }
                if($query['meta_key'] == "_company_name"){
                     $company = $xml_document->createElement("company");
                    $company->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection($query['meta_value']));
                    $job_element->appendChild($company);

                }
                }
    // Job ID


    // End Job Element
    $root->appendChild( $job_element );

}

echo $xml_document->saveXML();
echo $xml_document->save('/var/www/html/maifeed.xml');
```

Where is the error? Why it's not working?

Comment: $publisher->appendChild( $xml_document->createTextNode( "Latifa" ) ) );
unexpected )

Comment: $result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        foreach($result as $result){ you are the same name of a veriable do:  $results= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        foreach($results as $result)

Comment: Why do you end the PHP tag and start it right away?  I’d personally remove the excess tags.  ?><?php

Comment: the result will be something like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<source>
  <publisher>Latifa</publisher>
  <publisherUrl>https://www.latifa.com</publisherUrl>
  <job>
    <title><![CDATA[post_title]]></title>
    <applyUrl><![CDATA[guild]]></applyUrl>
    <description><![CDATA[post_content]]></description>
  </job>
</source>

Answer (score 1):

unexpected )

```
$publisher->appendChild( $xml_document->createTextNode( "Latifa" ) ) );
```

use:

```
$publisher->appendChild( $xml_document->createTextNode( "Latifa" ) );
```

you are the same name of a variable:

```
$result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql); foreach($result as $result){
```

use:

```
$results= mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
foreach($results as $result)
```

the same problem with:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$meta);
foreach($query as $query){
```

use:

```
$queries = mysqli_query($conn,$meta);
foreach($queries as $query){
```